# Constitutive Dark Skin vs Facultative Tanned Skin

Tags: human-biology, skin

Most can easily spot the difference between a tanned and dark person. But from my research, the only difference is in the size and concentration of melanin (Jablonski). But this continues to increase with sun exposure, so I was wondering what specific differences are there between people who tan or are naturally dark. Surely they are not the same color, so what is different?

Comment: note there are several forms of melanin.